# Do I need permission to use a species of creature from a story and add it to my own?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, species

I am wanting to do a story that revolves around Orcs.  Orcs are generic that any fantasy story can use them without getting any permission.  Would I be allowed to use Uruk-hai as a sub orc species (or a sub species similar but not called Uruk-hai) without the need to get permission?

Answer (score 7):

**Probably be a good idea.**

Tolkein's estate tends to be VERY protective of their intellectual properties, and (depending on what you're using it for), they might or might not care.

**I am not a lawyer, nor do I play one on TV.** There are plenty of fan works that use Tolkein's story elements that do just fine;  if you want to be sure, contact a lawyer.

**Uruk-hai is Black-Speech for Orc-folk.**  One way TSR (the guys who invented *Dungeons and Dragons*) got away with so much appropriation of other universe materials was to simply change the name and leave the thing relatively the same.  Just see what they did to Cthulhu mythos monsters.

You might just want to use "Orc-folk" or "Community Orcs" or "Yrchs" to separate them from "Common Orcs."  *Yrchs are a breed of orc specifically trained from youth as vicious fighters with no mercy.*

Comment: He might also draw names from Beowulf rather than LOTR.  Make it clear that you’re copying from what he copied from, not from him directly.

Comment: It's worth noting that unlike Elves (who got their current "Undying Badass" image from Tolkien but otherwise existed beforehand) Tolkien pretty much came up with Orcs as a variation of Goblins, to be a counterpart to Elves. So, other works using the term Orc have already taken it from Tolkien.

Comment: Historically elves and fairies were mean and nasty. Roughly around the Victorian Era, writers cleaned up their act, making their oh so terribly nice. Tolkien simply took them back to their roots as tough hombres.

Answer (score 2):

Publishers don't like being sued either. Sensibly they will  make you out your use of the Uruk-hai name. You will be asked to change it and they may further requesting changes to your descriptions and the nature of your orc stand-ins.

Worst of all, publishers may take one look of your use of Uruk-hai, drop your submission back into the slush pile and move on to the next manuscript. Publishers are busy, busy. They don't have time to waste. Anything that makes their job harder will work against a writer's submission.

Definitely not, without permission. However, the concept of Orcs is essentially non-copyrightable. Better to create your own version of Orcs and call them by whatever name you like.